# background color on Button in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-button, android-compose-button, android-jetpack-compose-button

```
Button(backgroundColor = Color.Yellow) {
    Row {
        Image(asset = image)
        Spacer(4.dp)
        Text("Button")
    }
}
```

I can not figure out why I can't use background color on `Button`.

I followed the Compose Layout codelabs.
There is a problem in `backgroundColor` and asset in Image().

Comment: PS: I'm also new to stackoverflow. So, please tell me what I did wrong :)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Use containerColor in place of backgroundColor when using Material 3

```
Button(
   onClick = {},
   colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Yellow)
) {
   /**/
}
```

Use `ButtonDefaults` which is available in 1.0.0-alpha09 to alpha11

```
Button(
   onClick = {},
   colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Yellow)
) {
   /**/
}
```

**OLD VERSION**

The `backgroundColor` for `Button` no longer work in `1.0.0-alpha7`

Use the below instead

```
Button(
   onClick = {},
   colors = ButtonConstants.defaultButtonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Yellow)
) {
   /**/
}
```

Comment: Intuition tells me `Modifier.background(Color)` should work here, but Google had other plans in store...

Comment: Why don't you use `Modifier` to set the color?

Comment: How will you verify the background using androidTest?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Because Google can't make a good Compose API to save their lives

Comment: If `backgroundColor = Color.Yellow` doesn't work, try `containerColor = Color.Yellow`. Some of the non-accepted answers mentioned this, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 84):

The background color is defined by the **`colors`** paramenter using the [**`ButtonDefaults.buttonColors`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ButtonDefaults#buttoncolors) function.

With **M2** you can specify the **`backgroundColor`** value:

```
Button(
     onClick = {  },
     colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
          backgroundColor = Color.White,
          contentColor = Color.Red)
)
```

With **M3** you can specify the **`containerColor`** value:

```
Button(
    onClick = {  },
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
        containerColor = Color.White,
        contentColor = Color.Red)
)
```

Comment: what about how to pass the onClick to another screen?

Comment: @FadelFarinsqi for example just use `startActivity(intent)` as a normal `Activity` in Android

Comment: what is M2, M3?

Comment: @StevenLee Material Design

Answer (score 22):

The `ButtonConstants.defaultButtonColor` is Deprecated at `1.0.0-alpha09` use :

```
 colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Yellow)
```

Update version 1.3.0 :

```
colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Yellow),
```

Comment: There is no 'containerColor' in 1.3.3.

Answer (score 13):

**Compose background buttons color**
create a variable mainButtonColor and define background Color and content Color

> ```
> implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha02'
> ```

```
    val mainButtonColor = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
        containerColor = androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color.Red,
        contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface
    )

    Row {
        Button(colors = mainButtonColor, onClick = {}, modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
            Text(text = "Custom colors")
        }
    }
```

[image: Change button color]

Answer (score 5):

The `ButtonDefaults.buttonColors` function returns a `ButtonColors` object, not a boolean value. Therefore, you need to pass the returned `ButtonColors` object to the colors parameter of the Button composable.

Here is an example of how you can use `ButtonDefaults.buttonColors` to set the background color of a Button:

```
    Button(
        onClick = { /* Do something */ },
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color(0xFFCA1212))
    ) {
        Text("Compose")
    }
```

This code sets the background color of the Button to `#CA1212` and displays the text `Compose` in the button. Note that you need to import `androidx.compose.material.Button` and `androidx.compose.material.ButtonDefaults` to use this code.

Answer (score 4):

**STEP 1: Simple only set bg:**

```
    Button(
        colors = buttonColors(Color.Red),
        onClick = {}
    ) {
        Text(text = "Login")
    }
```

**Full set colors:**

```
        Button(
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                backgroundColor = Color.Red,
                contentColor = Color.Green,
                disabledBackgroundColor = Color.Yellow,
                disabledContentColor = Color.Magenta
            ),
            onClick = {}
        ) {
            Text(text = "Login")
        }
```

**STEP 2 (optional): but this best practice**

**Material 2 case:**

```
    Color.Red change MaterialTheme.colors.primary
```

**Material 3 case:**

```
    Color.Red change MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiaryContainer
```

Answer (score 4):

The background color is defined by the colors paramenter using the ButtonDefaults.buttonColors function.

eg.

```
Button(
    onClick = { /* click */ },
    colors = ButtonDefaults.elevatedButtonColors(
                containerColor = Color.White,
                contentColor = Color.Red
            )
) {
    /* Your code */
}
```

Refer androidx.compose.material3.Button's buttonColors composable [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW54x.png)

Comment: This is the only option for Material 3, and this answer is WAY undervoted. If using M3 on buttons or outlined buttons the background parameter does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

#### Custom Colors

- To create a custom color you need the RGB value of that color.

```
         Button(
            onClick = {  },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    backgroundColor = Color(red = 255, green = 169, blue = 0)
                )
            ) {}
```

- `backgroundColor = Color(red = 255, green = 169, blue = 0)` is how we change the background color of the button to a custom color

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a pre-created colour or create your own using the RGB value of the colour.  ContentColor is the button text and containerColor is the button's background:

```
    Button(onClick = { },
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors
             (contentColor = Color.Black,   //pre-created colour
              containerColor = Color(255,255,157)))  // custom colour
```