# How to set JetpackCompose Button Background Color

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-button, android-compose-button, android-jetpack-compose-button

I tried the code in [background color on Button in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64376333/background-color-on-button-in-jetpack-compose)

```
Button(
    onClick = {  },
    backgroundColor = Color.Yellow) {
}
```

but it doesn't recognize `backgroundColor` anymore.

I tried the below

```
Button(
    modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Yellow),
    onClick = { }){
}
```

Doesn't error out but the color is not setting

I'm using `1.0.0-alpha07` of Jetpack Compose. What's the way to set background color of the button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Button(
   onClick = {},
   colors = ButtonConstants.defaultButtonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Yellow)
) {
   /**/
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [**`ButtonDefaults.buttonColors`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ButtonDefaults#buttoncolors) using the `backgroundColor` property:

Something like:

```
Button(
     onClick = {  },
     colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
          backgroundColor = Color.Red)
)
```

Comment: Ref for ButtonDefaults: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/ButtonDefaults
More on Themes: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes

Answer (score 0):

### In Material3:

It's changed a bit, you have to set `containerColor` to change background color.

#### Example:

```
    Button(
            onClick = { //todo },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                containerColor = Color.Yellow, // your background color
                contentColor = Color.Unspecified,// change text color
                disabledContainerColor = Color.Unspecified,
                disabledContentColor = Color.Unspecified
            ) 
        )
```

##### source: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/ButtonDefaults#buttonColors(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color)